# Modern Magento 1.X Workflow and Development Tools

Tags: magento-1, best-practice

I am new to Magento Development ( CE 1.6 ) and am still trying to define my workflow. I currently develop on Mac OSX 10.8 with Netbeans 7.3, but I find that Netbeans is slow and freezes on me. I tend to switch over to Sublime Text 2 to do quick viewing/editing of files, or I'll just pull up Vim sometimes for convenience.

**My questions**:

1. "**What does a modern Magento 1.X workflow look like?**"
2. "**What tools/configurations/plugins are best suited for Magento Development?**"

I know that this is a subjective thing, and there isn't going to be 'one workflow to rule them all', but I also believe that all of you certified/experienced developers would have some common choices. At the very least, I would expect some battle tested knowledge.

I would appreciate any input/feedback/suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609010/what-tools-and-extensions-are-critical-for-magento-development possibly related SO question, with similar input.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I agree that the list is subjective, but I suggest the following excellent tools I use every day:

- [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) IDE
- [Magento 2](https://github.com/dkvashninbay/magento2plugin) or [Magicento](http://magicento.com/) (Magento 1) IDE Plugin
- [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [github](https://github.com) for Version Management
- [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) and [magento-composer-installer](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/composer-with-magento/) for Dependency Management
- [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) PHP Debugger
- [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) Unit and Integration Testing
- [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) Module Manager to keep each modules source separated
- [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) Generic Magento CLI tool
- Since your're on OS X: [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) For quickly installing missing UNIX tools

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate you sharing with me tools you use on a daily basis. This is along the lines of what I'm looking for. I have done Google searches for Magento tools, and am more than capable of doing so. I wanted to see what other developers use.

Comment: +1 for Vinai. As for local server setup, maybe add Vagrant to the list, but I also like the PHP Package by Liip a lot, which installs the latest PHP on OSX with a decent php.ini. See http://php-osx.liip.ch/. For quickedits maybe take a look at Textmate. It's not as feature rich as ST, but it's free ;-)

Comment: @ryanF probably goes without saying, but I would add make sure you're working off of decent hardware.  I know people that use Sublime purely because they don't have a fast enough machine to make working with an IDE like PHP Storm snappy.

Comment: @kalenjordan thanks for the input. I'm working off of a MacBook Pro with the following specs: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. I had allocated ~750MB to my Netbeans, hoping that would be enough. Do you have any suggestions regarding good performance settings on Netbeans? *Yes, I do revert to ST when the big IDEs like Netbeans or Eclipse start freezing, doing too many background processes, or are just unresponsive in a reasonable manner. On the other hand, I'm subjected to having to stick with Netbeans/Eclipse when I want to drill down into my PHP. *shrugs*

Comment: That seems pretty good.  I was on a macbook pro and recently upgraded to a Mini - 2.6 Ghz Core i7, 8GB 1600 Mhz DDR3, with an SSD drive.  Made a huge improvement.  Get off of Netbeans, seriously - it's also a lot slower  than PHPStorm from what I recall from when I was using it.

Comment: Yea, I'm not rocking the SSD. So you prefer PHPStorm over Netbeans? I'll download the trial version and check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Was also Netbeans user, but trying Phpstorm+Magicento made me one happy developer :)

Comment: On OS X PHPStorm is a lot snappier then NB

Comment: @Vinai Do you think you could contribute to this question in the same way: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119870/magento-2-workflow-and-development-tools ?

Comment: i just created a new developer toolbar/profiler maybe its will suite your list :)
https://github.com/ecoco/magento_profiler

Comment: I don't recommend modman at all, it does pollute git on your server everytime when you deploy via modman...

Answer (score 20):

The other answers give a good list of tools to work with. Workflow will highly depend on type of projects and people involved. If you are starting out I would suggest investing into the following:

**1.) Automate the installation of Magento**
Set up a 1 command/click process to install Magento including sample data. Tools mentioned for this
[n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)
[mage-ci](https://github.com/EcomDev/MageCI)
[jumpstorm](https://github.com/netresearch/jumpstorm)
or your own script. Some pointers can be found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh).

The idea for this part is that you are able to create a fresh instance with repeatable settings without much effort (the moment effort is involved you will become hesitant/lazy to create a new instance)

**2.) Develop and test with the instance set up in 1.).**
For developing I have encountered two trains of thought:
*a.) Magento Core is part of your project*
Lots of folks use modman here, to keep their files outside of the Magento folder structure so be sure to check this out as well.
*b.) Project only includes the extension/theme files*
Both Phpstorm and Netbeans allow you to deploy on save to a specified location (your Magento root folder, can also be an online instance via FTP). Using Magicento for Phpstorm you can make up the disadvantages of this approach (class hinting, seeing inheritance, auto completion ...)
My gut feeling here is that if you are developing for one particular client you would go for 1.) with the targetted Magento version installed and if you intend to support multiple versions of Magento you would go for 2.)

**3.) Share code with team**
deploy into an environment where your code can be tested in conjunction with your colleagues' work

**4.) Start your QA/deploy process**

**Overall**
use a distributed version control system (git, mercurial, ...)
include tests ([unit tests](https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit), [integration](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageBehat))
automate what you can
read lots - follow some of the experts on here who freely share their knowledge (check their personal blogs/github accounts). More often than not this will save you lots of time and you will learn quicker than trying to discover it all yourself.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I appreciate the input regarding tips for developing a good workflow. I will take all your input into consideration. Thank you again!

Answer (score 13):

I personally like:

- all the things Vinai said already
- [Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) which supports git-flow
- [mage-ci](https://github.com/EcomDev/MageCI) for installing fast new magentos
- [MGT Developer toolbar](https://github.com/Schrank/Mgt_Developertoolbar) with a few fixes from me (auto-active and modman ready)
- [Ecomdev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit) for unit testing (dev branch!)

Comment: thanks for your additions to this list! Very cool tools offered here. I also appreciate the link to your improved MGT Developer toolbar. It's very cool to get insight into what the Industry professionals are using.

Answer (score 11):

I can advice following tools for Magento development.
1. [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) - excellent and clever IDE for development PHP applications.
2. [magicento](http://magicento.com/) plugin for PhpStorm. Very useful plugin for Magento development automation.
 
3. [Debug toolbar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug-8676.html) for Magento store.
4. [Advanced developer toolbar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-developer-tools.html) for Magento store.

And great sources and tuts here: 
http://alanstorm.com/category/magento 
http://inchoo.net/ 
http://magebase.com/category/magento-tutorials/ 
http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/

Comment: Thank you for offering feedback. It seems that the PhpStorm IDE is a popular one at the moment, especially with the Magicento plugin. I think the Magento plugins (#3 and #4 ) are really cool. Regarding the links to tutorials, I've already come across all of those ( Thank you for confirming those are good sources! ), and yes Alan Storm's material is at the top for me too. I have also found the Magento U 'Fundamentals of Magento Development" series to be really good so far ( I've just started ). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would add one more thing to the list:

When you are developing web services for Magento, for example when using the SOAP API, then this tool will help you to easily do requests and write repeatable steps to test workflows (login, fetch orders, fetch details of first order, create invoice):

http://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 3):

One more brand new developer toolbar/profiler its based on the awesome symfony web profiler and shows you nearly everything from missing translations to database queries and rendering time of individual blocks etc.

https://github.com/ecoco/magento_profiler