# Can I make a good ecommerce website with magento with zero knowledge of coding

Tags: magento2, learn-magento

I want to build a best e-commerce website with magento.
I don't want to use wordpress.

I can learn anything, so please recommend me any website or tutorial place from where I can learn these magento basic things, or tell me a short-cut for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Magento Plugin Development](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/learning-magento-plugin-development)

Answer (score 1):

My advise (from personal experience) would be if you have zero knowledge of coding then Magento might not be the best place to start.

I think you would be better off with a closed platform, as that would be "easier" to make a "good" site.  Magento is great but I don't think you can make a "great site" with its basic install ( as it missing some important stuff out of the box), and you would need extensions, maybe some custom coding and you would have to make sure its up to date with security updates and if you have extensions that can get complex.

But it really depends what you trying to do with your site, if you willing to learn code or pay other people to do the coding for you.