# Need help very urgent for my shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, tierprice

[image]

I am using magento 1.7 version i have configured everything well but i don't understand how this is coming. I have configured Fed-Ex shipping method ,but is there ihave to enable any rates or any other calculations.

Comment: the FedEx module costs over 200$, contact the support

Comment: @Flyingmana: I have already configured fed-ex shipping method off course it is an test account,but can you help me if any thing i have to configure to get rid of this error message.

Answer (score 1):

If the FedEx integration is a third party module you should contact the developer for support. They will likely ask for login details for your hosting account so they can check the situation.

This is not the kind of question that can easily be answered via a forum like StackExchange. Every Magento installation is different and there is no instant fix for an issue like this.

An alternative would be to get in contact with a certified Magento developer in your area:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/directory

If you want to try and debug the issue yourself I recommend you check out [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4494/modern-magento-workflow-and-development-tools) about the best tools to use when working with Magento.

Comment: No it was not any kind of third party module,i have just configured the fed-ex shipping module from the fed-ex website those which i have configured are just test account (sandbox account). So now i am thinking whetehr if i have enabled with fed-ex shipping method whether i have to enable any more things in my admin panel.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: yes jharrison i have flushed the entire cache even though the thing is same, can you help me out , whether there will be any kind of CSV files for fed-ex methods. also can you help me out how i have to enter my products weight, presently i have entered as 1.000 is that right.

Comment: Sorry @sudhir I'm based in Australia and have no experience with the FedEx module

Comment: Ok @JHarrison no problem thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable some shipping methods: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/shipping-carriers-setting-up-fedex (take a look at the Allowed Methods list secion). Also the error is about wrong address.

*fixed link*

Comment: i have already enabled fed-ex shipping methods but even though it was showing the same error message.