# Magento 2 Workflow and Development Tools

Tags: magento2, best-practice, workflow

I am curious what other members of the community are using and suggest for M2 development:

1. **"What are some suggested Magento 2.X workflows?"**
2. **"What tools/configurations/plugins are being used for Magento 2.X Development?"**

This is subjective, but I would still like to solicit community feedback.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Integer_Net made a great article about Magento 2 frontend workflow, I suggest you check it out: https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-frontend-workflow-step-by-step/

Basically the idea is:

- setup project's general structure
- setup Grunt environment
- create theme files
- start frontend workflow with Grunt

Regarding the useful tools, here are my suggestions based on my personal experience:

- **PHPStorm** IDE
- **Magicento 2**: http://magicento.com/
- Alan Storm's **CommerceBug module**: http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3
- **MageRun 2**: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2
- **xDebug**
- **modman**: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman

Comment: I appreciate your response (and inclusion of Commerce Bug 3). I am looking for more detailed information though. PhpStorm and JetBrains Magento 2 Plugin/Magicento 2, Z-Ray w/Magento 2 Plugin, Pestle, as examples. Any new tools that assist with the Magento Testing Framework? Any new tools that assist with new Php features in M2? SnowDog's FronTools? I'd like to see what others are using to get a sense of what's in play before awarding the answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for now, but would still be interested in seeing what others are doing.