# Tools and extension helpful in magento 2 development

Tags: magento2, extensions, development, discussion, tools

I am curious to know about extension and tools which can be helpful in Magento development i.e commerce bug, PHPstorm etc.

Nice reading [here from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609010/949003) and [from magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/119893/29175)

If this post will be off-topic, i will delete it.

I accept that its opinion based and also feel that @Magento StackExchange is great for this.

Comment: I think it's very Broad & Opinion based Topic. Helpful but not @Magento StackExchange i think

Comment: might be and I am expecting few basic tools which will help in fast development. And there would not be better platform than @Magento StackExchange

Comment: this question can be answer with some usable information and I request to reopen this.